# Using quadratic function with unknown constant term, How can i find these unknown constant using gradient descent?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, gradient-descent, derivative

everyone.

I am beginner of machine learning and start learning about gradient descent right now. However, I got a one big problem. Following question is like this :

```
given numbers [0,0],[1,1],[1,2],[2,1] and 
 equation will be [ f=(a2)*x^2 + (a1)*x + a0 ]
```

With hand-solving, i got a answer `[-1,5/2,0]`
but it is hard to find out the solution from making a python code with gradient descent with these given data.

In my case, I try to make a code with gradient descent method with easiest and fastest way like :

```
learningRate = 0.1

make **a series of number of x

initialize given 1,1,1 for a2,a1,a0

partial derivative for a2,a1,a0 (a2_p:2x, a1_p:x, a0_p:1)

gradient descent method : (ex) a2 = a2 - (learningRate)( y - [(a2)*x^2 + (a1)*x + a0] )(a2_p)
```

ps. Honestly, I do not know what should i put '`x' and 'y' or a2, a1, a0`.

However,  i got a wrong answer with different result each time.
So, I want to get a hint for correct equation or code sequence.

Thank you for reading my lowest level of question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few errors in your equations

For the **function** `f(x) = a2*x^2+a1*x+a0`, partial derivatives for `a2`, `a1` and `a0` are `x^2`, `x` and `1`, respectively.

Suppose **cost function** is `(1/2)*(y-f(x))^2`

**Partial derivatives of cost function** with respect to `ai` is `-(y-f(x))* partial derivative of f(x) for ai`, where `i` belongs to `[0,2]`

So, the **gradient descent equation** is: 
`ai = ai + learning_rate*(y-f(x)) * partial derivative of f(x) for ai`, where `i` belongs to `[0,2]`

I hope this **code** helps

```
#Training sample
sample = [(0,0),(1,1),(1,2),(2,1)]

#Our function => a2*x^2+a1*x+a0
class Function():
    def __init__(self, a2, a1, a0):
        self.a2 = a2
        self.a1 = a1
        self.a0 = a0
    
    def eval(self, x):
        return self.a2*x**2+self.a1*x+self.a0
    
    def partial_a2(self, x):
        return x**2
    
    def partial_a1(self, x):
        return x
    
    def partial_a0(self, x):
        return 1

#Initialise function
f = Function(1,1,1)

#To Calculate loss from the sample
def loss(sample, f):
    return sum([(y-f.eval(x))**2 for x,y in sample])/len(sample)

epochs = 100000
lr = 0.0005
#To record the best values
best_values = (0,0,0)

for epoch in range(epochs):
    min_loss = 100
    for x, y in sample:
       #Gradient descent
       f.a2 = f.a2+lr*(y-f.eval(x))*f.partial_a2(x)
       f.a1 = f.a1+lr*(y-f.eval(x))*f.partial_a1(x)
       f.a0 = f.a0+lr*(y-f.eval(x))*f.partial_a0(x)
    
    #Storing the best values
    epoch_loss = loss(sample, f)
    if min_loss > epoch_loss:
        min_loss = epoch_loss
        best_values = (f.a2, f.a1, f.a0)
       
print("Loss:", min_loss)
print("Best values (a2,a1,a0):", best_values)
```

**Output**:

```
Loss: 0.12500004789165717
Best values (a2,a1,a0): (-1.0001922562970325, 2.5003368582261487, 0.00014521557599919338)
```

Comment: Thank you for your kindness help!
However, I have to ask you about pop-up question to your answer.
First of all, if I have a multivariable like this or more, I have to think about x^n. x^n-1....1 respectively to calculate the unknown constant term?
Second, thank your help, now i understand the necessary concept of cost function and loss but still do not get them such as 'what is mean of loss with sample and sum for?','why min_loss=100?',
Third, if not make a condition for best values finder, what happen in that case?
Thank you for you help again!

Comment: This is a stochastic gradient descent, where for every point the loss is found and the update is made. I have additionally kept track of the average loss for the samples as a metric to check performance for each epoch. It doesn't interfere with gradient descent. The min_loss can be initialised to any large number, I just picked 100. During gradient descent, the values might overshoot the minima if the learning rate is large, thus to capture the values with least cost, I have recorded them as best values.

Comment: Now, I can understand your code! Thank you for your additional advice!